# How does Github calculate language percentage in a repo?

Tags: github

I have a repo with Ruby and PHP code in it.

Github says my repo is 74.8% PHP and 25.2% Ruby

I do not understand how this can be. When I compare the 2 languages in my project:

```
# Count how many files:

# Ruby
ls | grep ".*\.rb" | wc -l
# returns 10

#PHP
ls | grep ".*\.php" | wc -l
# returns 1


# Count how many lines, words, chars:

# Ruby
cat *.rb | wc
# returns 229, 812, 5303

# PHP
cat *.php | wc
# returns 102, 473, 2760
```

Ruby always seems to have more.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This really belongs on a Github help site/forum.

Comment: Check out [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist), GitHub's library for detecting languages and generating language breakdown graphs.

Comment: @DeadMG If it was on Github's help site/forum I would not have seen it. Hence, I like the fact that this interesting question is here.

Answer (score 27):

github uses [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist/) to detect languages in a project.

Linguist is open source. look into the source files and you'll find:

in `/bin/linguist`

```
repo.languages.sort_by { |_, size| size }.reverse.each do |language, size|
  percentage = ((size / repo.size.to_f) * 100).round
  puts "%-4s %s" % ["#{percentage}%", language]
end
```

in `/lib/linguist/file_blob.rb`

```
 # Public: Get byte size
 #
 # Returns an Integer.
 def size
   File.size(@path)
 end
```

so it actually use file sizes to determine the language percentage.

also keep in mind that binary data, vendored files, generated files, and non-program files are excluded.